# Escaping the field separator in SSIS data export

Tags: ssis, bcp

My SQL table contains the following data:

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ Column 1 ║  Column 2  ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║ |Some Data ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

This data is then exported to a Pipe (|) delimited Text file like this:

```
1||Some Data
```

When I try to import this data using BCP with the format file, it obviously fails.

I then try to generate with the file with text qualifier:

```
1|"|Some Data".
```

However, this is also failing.  What is the purpose of text qualifier?  How do I tell bcp to use |" as the field separator for the second column?

Comment: As a sanity check can you import the file into Excel or back into your database?

Answer (score 0):

If using BCP, you need to use a format file. There are other answers around to help but here's an answer I gave to another that includes mention of why you need the format file.

[SQL Server BCP Export where comma in SQL field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170391/sql-server-bcp-export-where-comma-in-sql-field/52191402#52191402)

Essentially, the bcp format file (the -f option, use it instead of the -t option to specify field delimiter) allows you complete control over each field's delimiter. You'll want to set the delimiter to quote-your delimiter-quote.

That's.... ("|") in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using BCP, but the SSIS tag is attached to the question so some details on doing this process using SSIS are below.

- Create a Flat File Connection Manager.  Since you already have the
  data exported to a file, on the Flat File Connection Manager Editor
  page, click the Browse button next to the File Name field and select
  your file.  Depending on the file extension, you may need to change
  the extension property when browsing the file system.
- Set the format to delimited, pick a text qualifier if this is used,
  and check the "Column names in the first data row" option if this
  applies.
- On the Columns pane, select `Vertical Bar {|}` for the Column
  Delimiter property and the appropriate Row Delimiter.
- In the Advanced pane, add column names if they weren't in the file. 
  Also make that the correct data types are used.  These will likely
  default to text data.  For additional info on SSIS data types and
  matching them to the corresponding types in SQL Server, see this
  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-2017).  Make sure to preview the data before running the package too.
- If a text qualifier is used, set the `TextQualified` property to true for only the text columns, otherwise make sure it is false.
- Verify that the account running the package has the proper permissions to access the file as well as the tables that the data will be loaded to.