# bcp query skip comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

The issue i am having is that i have data in sql columns which have "," in the data

**Example column** : Text,Text2,text3

so i want to skip the "," so it will not going to effect my data otherwise it just messing up the data

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * from details queryout "\\TEst\Share\32\123Test.csv" /c /t, -T'
```

Comment: regarding the column that has a comma included, is that field quoted for all rows? (that'd be good) Or is the field only quoted when there is a comma in the data? (this will be more work)

Comment: all rows there are multiple column

Comment: we've had to just replace the commas, or use a different delimiter with bcp.

Comment: replacing the commas is one way to go, but that introduces (possibly) another technology into the solution; some script language to parse. That's not bad but if you can avoid a 2nd technology in a solution, I would avoid it. You can load this file with purely SQL Server and BCP.

Comment: not just commas.. carriage returns and line breaks as well.. bcp could be so much better with a few more options

Comment: JamieD77, yes if the data is plagued with lots of dirty bytes of control/formatting data, then yes, some form of "cleansing" is required at some point. But the poster here only mentioned commas which are desired and expected to be in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since this file has quoted values and the quoted values are quoted on every record (not JUST the values that contain commas) you can use this solution.

Essentially you need to use a BCP format file with the -f option. With the format file you can specify custom field delimiters. So, in your case, the delimiters will be customized to no longer be just a comma (,) but will now include the quotes as well (",").

It gets a little tricky if the first or last fields are quoted, but that can be done too. See here:

[SQL Server BCP Bulk insert Pipe delimited with text qualifier format file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958418/sql-server-bcp-bulk-insert-pipe-delimited-with-text-qualifier-format-file/55959635#55959635)

or here:

[SQL Server BCP Export where comma in SQL field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170391/sql-server-bcp-export-where-comma-in-sql-field/52191402#52191402)