# bcp error ignore delimiters (String data, right truncation)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bcp

So I'm using bcp to import a csv file to my SQL database.
This is the command:

```
bcp table in D:\temp\some_file.csv -T -S serverName -d dbName -F 2 -c -t "," -r "\n"
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to import the file:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation

24 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 31     Average : (774.19 rows per sec.)
```

The last 2 columns of the csv file contains User full name ("surname, name"), Customer full name ("surname, name")

```
SYS Hostname,SYS Domain,User Name,Customer Name
server1,test.com,"surname, name","surname2, name2"
```

Is it possible to ignore the , between the ""?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

As @AlwaysLearning said:

> You have a Quoted CSV file which is something the bcp.exe process
> cannot handle. As per RFC4180 your data row has four fields server1
> test.com surname, name and surname2, name2 but bcp.exe only sees the
> commas so thinks it is six fields. Consider alternative methods - such
> as using a PowerShell script to load the data file into a DataTable
> using Import-Csv and then insert the DataTable using an SqlBulkCopy
> object over an SQL connection

There is any other option to import a CSV file by command line o SQL script?

Thanks

Comment: You have a Quoted CSV file which is something the bcp.exe process cannot handle. As per [RFC4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) your data row has four fields `server1` `test.com` `surname, name` and `surname2, name2` but bcp.exe only sees the commas so thinks it is six fields. Consider alternative methods - such as using a PowerShell script to load the data file into a `DataTable` using `Import-Csv` and then insert the `DataTable` using an `SqlBulkCopy` object over an SQL connection.

Comment: Unless the use of quoted strings is variable (double quotes only appear in the name columns if the names actually include a comma) then yes, BCP cannot be made to work on its own.  However, if the name fields will always contain the double-quotes, then BCP can handle such a file.

Comment: If you can remove the header, you can just import it as six columns, and stick the data together afterwards. BTW if you have any choice in the matter, a comma is one of the worst delimiters you can use.

Answer (score 0):

See this response here. BCP can work so long as the quoted fields are always quoted, on every line of the file. Regardless of whether the name value contains a comma or not. The question below is regarding export, but it works the same on import. You essentially tell BCP that the delimeter is "," and not just ,

[SQL Server BCP Export where comma in SQL field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170391/sql-server-bcp-export-where-comma-in-sql-field/52191402?noredirect=1#comment118708998_52191402)